# Overriding Private Members of Parent Class

Tags: c++

Given the following classes:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int c;

public:
    foo( int a = 42 ) { c = a; }
    ~foo();
};

class bar: public foo
{
public:
    bar();
    ~bar();
};
```

How can I make **bar** override **c** with a different number? Can I do something like this?

```
bar::bar() 
{
    c = 12;
}
```

I get this error when trying to compile:

> test.cpp: In constructor `‘bar::bar()’`:
>   test.cpp:8:7: error: `‘int foo::c’` is private

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call your base class' constructor in the constructor initialization list:

```
bar::bar()
  : foo(12)
{ }
```

Incidentally, you should **always** prefer using a constructor initialization list over assignment inside the constructor body, so your `foo` constructor would be better written as:

```
foo( int a = 42 ) : c(a) { }
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know you could do that with parent class constructors. I thought it was only member variables. Can you provide me some more insight as to why it is better to use the initialisation lists over assignment?

Comment: @druciferre : It's better to use initialization lists over assignment because initialization lists actually _initialize_ your members; assignment merely assigns a value to an already-initialized variable. For POD types like `int`, this doesn't matter one way or another; but for class types e.g. `std::string`, `std::vector<>`, or any class _you_ make, the difference in terms of efficiency can be dramatic. Also, types without a default constructor, reference types, and const types **must** be initialized in the initialization list -- no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Call the base class constructor:

```
bar::bar() : foo(12) { }
```

Edit: whoops

Answer (score 1):

You should use getter and setter methods for your private variables.

So your calls foo should look like this:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int c;

public:
    foo( int a = 42 ) { c = a; }
    virtual ~foo();
    void setC (int tempC){
         c=tempC;
    }
    int getC() const{
        return c;
    }
};
```

In the constructor of B you can call them the setter method:

```
bar::bar() 
{
    setC(12);
}
```

You should then always use your setter and getter methods to access your variable, instead of accessing it direct.

You should also declare your destructor of your base class virtual.

Comment: "*You should also declare your destructor of your base class virtual.*" I disagree -- there's no evidence that the classes are being used polymorphically.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
bar::bar() : foo(12) {}
```